# Find authors who ONLY wrote history books

Tags: sql

New to SQL, although catching on - stuck on this query.
This works, although Paddy O'Furniture should not be showing up as this author hasn't written any book and his au_id does not appear in the title_authors table. Please help.

Find authors who ONLY wrote history books

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname

from authors a

where not exists(

    select ta.au_id

    from title_authors ta

    join titles t

    on t.title_id = ta.title_id

    where t.type != 'history'

    and a.au_id = ta.au_id

)
```

Output:

A01 Buchman Sarah

A07 O'Furniture Paddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach can work if you use another `exists` to make sure the author wrote at least a history book, here's another approach using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
from authors a
    join title_authors ta on a.au_id = ta.au_id
    join titles t on ta.title_id = t.title_id
group by a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
having sum(case when t.type != 'history' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/PHS49807)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Paddy O'Furniture is in your result because no matching rows were discovered in the correlated subquery. i.e. no rows `exist` for that author and hence `where not exists` is true.

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
from authors a
inner join title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
inner join titles t on ta.title_id = t.title_id
group by a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
having count(case when t.type <> 'history' then 1 end) = 0
```

The approach above uses a case expression within a count() function so that if any books have a non history type this count will be greater than zero. The `having` clause enables using aggregated values to filter the final result (having is used is AFTER the `group by` clause, and is not a substitute for a `where` clause).

Comment: Thank you. This explanation helps get me started. I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Adding `JOIN` to `title_authors` on the outer query will filter out authors who have not written a book.

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
from authors a
join title_authors ta1 on ta1.au_id = a.au_id
where not exists(
    select 1
    from title_authors ta
    join titles t on t.title_id = ta.title_id
    where t.type != 'history' and ta1.id = ta.id
)
```

The `title_authors` in the inner query can actually be removed.

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
from authors a
join title_authors ta on ta.au_id = a.au_id
where not exists(
    select 1
    from titles
    where t.type != 'history' and title_id = ta.title_id
)
```

Comment: I like this one, however I do not understand the 'select 1' - maybe I'm not far enough in my course to understand this.